# Анимация из Adobe After Effect в Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, анимация, android-animation, adobe

Можно как то анимацию из Adobe Effect перетащить в Android studio ? Или как к примеру в Android studio можно делать сложные анимации типо этой ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AyrKzmiDww

Comment: в теории можно, эффект резкой смены и возврата картинки можно легко добиться с помощью DrawableAnimation а вот перелистывание по буквам, нужно постараться. Я делал похожий эффект давно, использовал ValueAnumator ну и Canvas, получилось неплохо, а тут придется ещё порисовать норм. Но в теории да - можно. Если нужно организовать, чисто как заставку, один раз, то первый вариант быстро решит проблему, только нужно нарисовать.

Answer (score 1):

Анимации можно самому запекать, но не все, эффекты не поддерживаются.

Закидываешь в [АЕ](https://aescripts.com/bodymovin/) и запекаешь как JSON файл с помощью bodymovin.
После идешь в [lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android) и подключаешь в Android Studio, заливаешь запеченный JSON и всё.

Нюансы в FAQ по [lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android).